# Как асинхронно добавить текст в listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, асинхронность

У меня такой вопрос: как можно асинхронно добавить текст в listbox? Допустим, чтобы числа постоянно добавлялись в список.

Comment: @rifat2125, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, вам надо генерировать числа асинхронно (на Task'ах, на callback'ах или просто в другом потоке) и добавлять из в ListBox обычным образом.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (listbox.InvokeRequired)
{
   Invoke(new Action(() => AddText(text)));
}
else
{
   AddText(text)};
};
....
}
void AddText(string text)
{
   listbox.Add(text) //или любое действие с listbox
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем делать это асинхронно? При добавлении элемента в ListBox текущий поток не блокируется.

Comment: @ZBoT, @VladD, Дело в том, что я хочу сделать запись из буфера обмена в listbox. Запись идет сразу, без всяких нажатий кнопок. А listbox ругается, что-то там с потоком.. вот)

Comment: @rifat2125: Странно. Покажите лучше код.

Comment: @VladD, я не знаю, что я до этого делал, но сейчас у меня нет этой ошибки. Зато у меня новая проблемка: как мне записать из буфера обмена содержимое в listbox и каждый раз, когда буфер будет меняться, будет писаться новая запись в listbox

Comment: @rifat2125: Тогда задайте отдельный вопрос, т. к. это уже новая проблема.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте это:

```
CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

Comment: Вот классный совет-то. «Запретить проверку на недопустимые обращения из другого потока.» То есть не починить, а замазать проблему.